# No se ven imágenes remotas con Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, ionic-framework

Tengo una aplicación que desde hace unas semanas se me vienen quejando los clientes de que no pueden ver las imágenes (aparece el icono de enlace a imagen roto).

Al parecer no le ocurre a todo el mundo, pero a muchos sí. El único cambio que se ha experimentado que pueda justificar este problema es que se cambió el protocolo del servidor al que se llaman las imágenes de `http://` a `https://`, pero el que algunas personas vean las imágenes y otras no, me tiene confundido.

Yo mismo en probado en móviles más o menos antiguos y se ven sin problemas, al parecer ocurre con dispositivos más modernos. No sé si tendrá algo que ver el protocolo o es algo del plugin whitelist.

Comment: Están actualizadas esas aplicaciones? igual seguís buscando por ruta http.

Comment: las imágenes se muestran directamente en el src. Es decir, lo que viene del servidor es la url completa: "https://dominio.com/ruta/de/la/imagen.jpg" con el https// incluido

Comment: Las habéis depurado? para ver que esta trayendo. Esas imagenes "rotas" tenéis que mirar a que url se están dirigiendo. Podéis tener el problema de la dirección o que no se están pintando bien esas url por X razón.

Comment: es complicado depurarlas, ya que en los dispositivos que tenemos se ven perfectamente.Las imágenes se han visto bien hasta hace unas semanas, aunque no puedo asegurar que fuera justo cuando el cambio de protocolo. Otra cosa es lo que comentas, que no se estén pintando bien, pero al no poder depurarlas porque a nosotros no nos falla...

Comment: Si sabéis en que dispositivo esta fallando podéis simularlo. También podría se tema de permisos que le den los usuarios a la aplicación.